# How to change "Privacy Policy" footer link

Tags: magento2.3, footer-links

I am looking to amend the link to the Privacy Policy in my Magento 2.3.x installation. It is currently pointing to /privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode however I would like it to point to /privacy-policy.

I have inserted the following code to default.xml and cleared my cache but it has no effect. I'm struggling to troubleshoot.

```
 <!-- Corrects Privacy Policy Link -->
    <referenceBlock name="footer_links">

    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode">

    <arguments>

    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Privacy Policy</argument>

    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">privacy-policy</argument>

    </arguments>

    </block>

    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way I ended up fixing this issue is by removing the link from the footer and re-adding my custom Privacy Policy link to a static block in the footer.

Achieves the same result and looks like the cleanest solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with footers links are have from two place :

1. in cms block `footer_links_block` you can edit which will effect in footer
2. all core module search `referenceBlock="footer_links"` in `xml` files where ever they added links and display in footer

Comment: I can not find the CMS block you are referring too?

Comment: can you please check with xml  / second option

Comment: check with this path - vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Comment: There is no such folder in my installation

Comment: vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Comment: Okay, that file exists. I have amended the privacy policy link, updated cache and the footer is still directing to the initial link. Very strange.

Comment: i tested my side its working please check with your theme or other code, some where exists code

Comment: How else can I search for references to footer links in cms files?

Comment: are you working in local ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: than explore your m2 directory in subline than search. that's it